# Deploy Node js app to local windows machine

Tags: node.js

I created a Node.js app (firebase-admin) that reads/writes data from our local SQL Server, reads/writes data to Firebase Realtime Database. This part is working now. My other desktop apps will connect to this Node.js app to request data from firebase RTDB. This part is also working.

I would like now to host the Node.js app in our LAN. How do I setup the host machine so that the desktop apps (also from the same LAN) will connect like http://local ip of host machine/name of app. Example, http://192.168.1.254/firebasemiddleware/. Also, if I have another app, let's say named anothermiddleware, the local address should be, http://192.168.1.254/anothermiddleware/.

This machine is behind a firewall and will not be visible from outside the LAN.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a web server as reverse proxy. Look at Caddy for example.

Comment: Install node.js on the host/deploy your app and use a reverse proxy. NGINX is perfect for this. Also a DNS Name would be nicer, since you can check the host header and forward the request to the re right app. E.g. firebase.lan -> app1, middleware.lan -> app2

Comment: I ended up just pointing to the IP address:port.

Answer (score 0):

You could run [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as a reverse proxy to pass through based on address to your
multiple local services.

You would setup a reverse proxy on Nginx like this:

```
location /firebasemiddleware {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

location /anothermiddleware {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
}
```

The docs on this are [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

If you're new to this there is a really cool configuration generator by digital ocean that might make life easier for you located [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx)

Answer (score -1):

Your network is currently a local area network and you cannot allow external connections to access it.
**Option 1**: you find out about the nat of the current carrier that is providing you and open the corresponding port of the nodejs app you are running with nat's port and access it through the public ip, get the public ip by accessing  some websites for example: https://whatismyipaddress.com/en-vn/index.
**Option 2**: simpler if you don't have a static ipv4 address or can't open nat of your carrier, then you can use tunnel, recommend to learn https://www.cloudflare.com/products/tunnel/ .

Comment: I don't want to access the machine from outside. I want to access it only from inside the LAN. But right now, I access it using http://localhost:3000/requeststocklevelapi. I want to use a proper name for my app, like http://192.168.1.254/firebasemiddleware/requeststocklevelapi

Comment: All I want is to have a proper network address for my app